# Emberjs form, submit function and action helper errors

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/ACzaJ/7/ 
 This fiddle  has the following problems:

1. When you click: 'clear completed button' you will get the error:

   ```
   Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Target <Ember.View:ember116> does not have action clearCompletedTodos

     And this line generates that error:
    <button {{action clearCompletedTodos  target="Todos.todosController" }} >
         Clear Completed Todos
     </button>
   ```
2. I am experimenting with two different submit functions, comment one out per time to try the other:

   2a. When i click 'add' button, when using the first submit function by commenting out the second one, no new todo is added and no error is theown. That is nothing happends.

   2b. When i comment out the first submit function and use the second submit function, clicking add, throws the error below:

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createTodo' of null.
   ```

How can i make this todo app,  run and add and clear todos. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Question 1 is now resolved by @pauldechov. But **question 2a and 2b** is unresolved. The jsfiddle link has been updated too. Thanks @pauldechov.

**UPDATE 2**

The solution provided by Peter here later had issues and Peter resolved the new issues here:

[Previously working emberjs1.0-pre form on jsfiddle returns "error": "Please use POST request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150929/previously-working-emberjs1-0-pre-form-on-jsfiddle-returns-error-please-use)

Comment: App.todoController is a typo (the original definition). Should be App.todosController like all of the references.

Comment: @pauldechov thanks. That fixed question 1, but the issues in question 2a and 2b are still occuring. Do you have any suggestion on those. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it looks like you've given your `TodoView` an `id` with spaces in it. This `id` needs to be a valid HTML id so that will definitely cause some problems. Secondly, the `submit` function is looking for a value on your instance of `TodoFormView`. However, the value is defined on your `TodoView` instance. You need to set up a binding between the two.

I've simplified things a bit by getting rid of `TodoView` for now and just using a standard `TextField`. Also, your `remaining` function needed to be changed to do `get('length')` with quotes instead of `get(length)`. Additionaly, the checkbox API has changed from some of the older examples, see http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Checkbox.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wagenet/ACzaJ/8/

Comment: Rather than use jsfiddle provided in the solution here, which later had issues, refer to how the issues were solved still with Peter's help here ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150929/previously-working-emberjs1-0-pre-form-on-jsfiddle-returns-error-please-use