# Previously working emberjs1.0-pre form on jsfiddle returns "error": "Please use POST request"

Tags: ember.js

This code  ** http://jsfiddle.net/wagenet/ACzaJ/8/ **  was working a few days ago, when i returned to it today, it throws **{"error": "Please use POST request"}**, when i click **add button**
Also the jsfiddle editor.js always throws exception on this line:
**function stop(){cc = stop; throw StopIteration;};**
Does anyone knows the cause of this issue.

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

***Kindly scroll down to see the many updates i posted as an answer to supplement Peter's initial answer.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

1. You're not actually using 1.0 pre, you're using master.
2. In master, you need to call `App.initialize()` for event listeners to work
3. You shouldn't be setting up an `{{action}}` helper on the button. The form view already has  a `submit` method that will automatically be called when the `submit` event happens on the form.
4. There's an issue with the `valueBinding`. It appears to be an Ember bug as it works if you remove the `id="new-todo"`.
5. After resolving all of this, I was also seeing a Metamorph error. I didn't attempt to debug farther than this since you probably should just use 1.0 pre for now.

Comment: Many thanks for always helping out. The form can now log inputs or values to the console after i removed the id=''new-todo'' and followed your other guidelines. But, i still have this **{"error": "Please use POST request"}** to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1**

Based on @Peter Wagenet's suggestions below, the form now logs entries or inputs to the console but it doesn't display on the result section of jsfiddle instead what is displayed on jsfiddle result section or page is still this error {"error": "Please use POST request"}

** http://jsfiddle.net/ACzaJ/18/

**Update 2**

In this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ACzaJ/19/, i have successfully eliminated this error {"error": "Please use POST request"} by adding event.preventDefault(); to the submit action in Todos.TodoFormView. That allows us to use arbitrary view methods as action handlers.

The existing issue is that the input to the form, only displays on the console and not on jsfiddle result section, though no error displays on the result section, there is a new error appearing in the console of the updated fiddle:

*Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.*

**Finally solved**

I needed to comment out App.initialize() for it to work as expected, also see point 2 of Peter's answer. This the working fiddle ** http://jsfiddle.net/ACzaJ/20/.

Similar to the working fiddle above but with id="new-todo" specified for the textfield, so it means ember has no bug affecting 'id' see point 4 of Peter's. http://jsfiddle.net/ACzaJ/21/

I don't know why using App.initialize() was making the app not to work, but my guess is that, App.initialize works with other parts like the router for routing, ApplicationController and ApplicationView with {{outlet}} in the handlebars, which i didn't need for this fiddle.

**Finally Finally and completely solved**

** http://jsfiddle.net/tQWn8/, ** http://jsfiddle.net/tQWn8/1/ (2nd link works with id specified). I was able to get it to works with App.initialize. But i had to declare all those components listed the prior paragraph above and pass the router to App.initialize, like this App.initialize(router). If you don't do this, then you will get the old error

*Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.*

For more, see the Documentation for emberjs initialize function:

http://docs.emberjs.com/?#doc=Ember.Application&method=initialize&src=false

Many thanks to Peter Wagenet for his guide